# Translate Mailchimp success response in custom HTML form

Tags: validation, mailchimp

Any ideas how translate .js success response

"*Almost finished... We need to confirm your email address. To complete the subscription process, please click the link in the email we just sent you.*"

```
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="">Almost finished... We need to confirm your email address. To complete the subscription process, please click the link in the email we just sent you.</div>
```

From custom Mailchimp signup form?

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        (function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';}(jQuery));
            $.extend($.validator.messages,{
                required: "To pole jest wymagane.",
                remote: "Proszę o wypełnienie tego pola.",
                email: "Proszę o podanie prawidłowego adresu email.",
                success: "Już prawie gotowe ... Musimy jeszcze potwierdzić Twój adres e-mail. Aby zakończyć proces subskrypcji, kliknij link w e-mailu, który właśnie co Ciebie wysłaliśmy.",
                pattern: $.validator.format( "Pole zawiera niedozwolone znaki." )
            });
            var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    </script>
```

Trying to add 'success' to validator.messages but without success

Answer (score 1):

This message can be translated on [mailchimp.com](https://mailchimp.com).

Log in, go to Audience > Signup forms > Form Builder > Translate it > select 'Signup thank you page'.